# Usercontrol namespace error visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, user-controls, visual-studio-2022

I recently upgraded visual studio from version 2017 to 2022.
Now I'm having some very annoying problems.

I have a c#.net WPF project with about 25 usercontrols, all in the same namespace (MyProject.Usercontrols)

When one usercontrol won't compile, I will get an error for every instance of every usercontrol, saying that that usercontrol does not exist in namespace MyProject.Usercontrols.

So I get a list of hundreds of errors that I know are wrong. It can take me a while to find the actual error causing the problem. When I fix that one error, all of those namespace errors disappear.

Sometimes it won't even show me the real error and I get nothing but incorrect namespace errors. (I literally couldn't find the problem so i just had load an old backup and try again)

I never had problems like this is version 2017. Is there a setting I can change?
I've searched hard but i cannot find any thread with the same problem.

I'm not sure how to deal with this, I'm tempted to just go back to version 2017.

Comment: Please provide at least the error message you receive. But it sound correct that if you break the usercontrols project than other projects that reference the usercontrols project wont find what they are searching for. But that depends on what you break and how you referenced the project. Did you just reference the resulting dll or do you have project dependencies?

Comment: Often best to work your way up from the last error.  But how do not know what you're changing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ask a different question, why are these namespaces failing at all? I've moved wpf projects from 2017 to 2019 to 2022 and haven't experienced this issue to this or any degree.  I would advise to be more proactive and anticipate what will fail based on what you have seen so far.

If you are overwhelmed, create a single project and move one control into it (controls should stand on their own right?), determine its issue, and verify that your other controls do not follow the same failure pattern.